# Web Interface for Embedded Controller - is Node.JS suitable?

Tags: node.js, websocket, ejs

I have been tasked with creating a Web Interface for an Embedded device that currently runs a C++ App which controls LED Signs out in the field. The C++ App basically talks serial protocol with the signs via RS-232 and collects vital information such as pixel health, temperature of sign, luminosity, frame being displayed etc..

The powers that be would like this some control over the signs via a Web Interface as well as access to this information described above via a Web Interface.

I have been given a protocol to query the C++ App via a TCP Socket. So what I need to do is query the App via a TCP Socket and somehow get this information to the Web Interface and vice versa in terms of controlling the Signs.

The Embedded Controller is an ARM v7, I believe capable of running Node.JS.

Is Node.JS suitable for this task or should I look at something else?

Not entirely sure how to get the content from the Node.JS App to the browser as yet.

[Pic showing the different components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4iQZ.png)

Comment: Any reason the embedded device with LEDs must be a web server (as in "delivering browser-ready content") at the same time?

Comment: Sorry not sure I follow what you're asking. They have asked for a Web Interface for the controller so they can control the Signs the Controller talks to as well as get the status of the signs.

Comment: Yes this is definitely doable in nodejs. I'm working on something similar and can't see any reason it shouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks Molda. Any hints on what I should be looking to use when it comes to displaying the information I receive from the controller on the Web pages? From what I've read I should be looking at templates to inject the info into my static html pages?